# Shutter installs every time I use it

Tags: shutter

When I install 'shutter' through the software center it works in a really annoying way. Every time I open the program it seems to have to unpack it and install it...it doesn't just 'open' like every other program.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about and have ways of alleviating this?

If I run 'shutter' in terminal, I get this output (keep in mind this is a fresh install of ubuntu):

```
    defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/bin/shutter line 3736.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
    defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/bin/shutter line 3747.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
    WARNING: gnome-web-photo is missing --> screenshots of websites will be 
disabled!

    WARNING: Net::DBus::GLib is missing --> Ubuntu One support will be 
disabled!

    WARNING: Image::ExifTool is missing --> writing Exif information will be 
disabled!

    INFO: There is already another instance of Shutter running!
```

It also loaded the program (but it happened automatically this time and didn't have to 'install' it first like it does when I click the icon in the UI to start it up.

Comment: What is the output if you  type in a terminal `shutter`?

Comment: interesting. I added that to my original Q - do I just need to install those other tools or is there more going on here?